# How to remove Binding from BindableProperty via DataTrigger in Xamarin.Forms (XAML)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, datatrigger

Since it is possible to add a Binding to a BindableProperty via DataBinding, should also be able to remove Binding from BindableProperty via DataTrigger?

```
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="MyStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference mySwitch}, Path=IsToggled}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="Name" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference mySwitch}, Path=IsToggled}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!--The Binding removal should occur here-->
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

*Of course, I'm talking about removing from the Style level in XAML, not from the code level. From the code level, we can do [BindableObject.RemoveBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.removebinding?view=xamarin-forms), but how to do it in XAML?*

Comment: Probably set it to `<x:Null />`

Comment: This change does not removes the Binding from the BindableProperty. Refreshing Source will cause Label.Text to receive the value from Source again. Something tells me that the authors of XF did not foresee such an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Path="null"` but I checked when it loads first time `IsToggled=True` I can see Text being set, when I change i.e `IsToggled=False` the switch the text is blank. That's what is expected according to your question.

However when I toggle switch again `IsToggled=True` I don't see the text with the binding `Name` however.

It doesn't seem there is XAML that is exactly equivalent to `BindableObject.RemoveBinding` I think good bet is to rely on C# code for the same.

**Update:**

One more trigger when `IsToggled=false` is **not required** at all. Just remove it. The first trigger activates and binds only when `IsToggled=True` when its false  `Binding` is itself removed.

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Label"
               x:Key="MyStyle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                             Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference mySwitch}, Path=IsToggled,Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
             <!-- end of all triggers -->
            </Style.Triggers>
          <!-- end of style -->
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

**`IsToggeled=true`**
[image: IsToggeled=true]

**`IsToggeled=false`**
[image: IsToggeled=false]

I tested this and it works. Hope this is what you are looking for.

[image: testing]

Comment: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Source. Report Raise (FirstName) in set for FirstName. Change your name e.g. in code behend or by coomand.

Comment: Yes,its bound to ViewModel which has implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and triggers OnPropertyChanged event when setter is called

Comment: OK I understand. It works badly as is Entry and not Label and when Binding is TwoWay.

Comment: Yes. set the binding to `Mode=TwoWay` and I confirmed changing value from code behind for each toggle, it works . So its all good now. Please upvote and accept if it works for you.

Comment: I checked for Entry and it does not work unless I'm blind :(

Comment: I think you need to post another question if binding doesnt work for Entry,

Comment: You're right, thank you. Tomorrow I will try to investigate and describe the case more closely because there was some confusion. Thank you for your support.